# Error IndexOutOfBoundsException when scroll to new posts

Tags: android, scroll, retrofit, adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

i am noob and want to make app with json api and WordPress as backend. i can fetch the posts and it works fine untill first page posts, when i click on each post i can see the post detail as well, but on next page post or when scroll to next page, click doesn't work and app crashes,but i can see the post images as well in next page but not post details. i have searched lot but nothing seems to work for me. the error i got is this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 10
```

when i click on 12th post i see this

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 10
```

i don't know how can i make size more than 10 as well..

i have searched lot on google but did not get any solution..

this is my code to load more posts

```
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) { //check for scroll down
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;
                        Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                        // Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                    yourURL = "https://punjabidharti.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories=4514&per_page=10" + "&page=" + pageNo++;
                        getRetrofit();
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and GetRetrofit

```
 public void getRetrofit(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
    String yourURl = yourURL.replace(baseURL,"");
    Call<List<WPPost>>  call = service.getPostInfo( yourURl);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
            Log.e("mainactivyt", " response "+ response.body());
            mListPost = response.body();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (response.body() != null) {


                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++ ) {


                    Log.e("size", list.size() + "");


                    System.out.println("The shortest word i is:" + i );




                    Log.e("main ", " title " + response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered() + " " +
                            response.body().get(i).getId());
                    String tempdetails = response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("<p>", "");
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("</p>", "");
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("[&hellip;]", "");
                    list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                            tempdetails,
                            response.body().get(i).getImages().getMedium()));





                }




                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

change loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= mListPost .size(); i++ )
```